# git rejected push non-fast-forward

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit

I am quite new to git, and I had been working on a small side project for the last 2 months and had been pushing stuff onto bitbucket with no problems. A couple of days ago, I zipped my project folder (since I had to reinstall my Linux OS) and now unzipped this after my reinstallation of Linux OS.

So, now, I went to my project folder, kept happily working and finally did:

```
git add -A && git commit -m "modified code" && git push origin master
```

..which is what I usually do..

and I get:

```
To https://johnsproject@bitbucket.org/johnsproject/proj.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://johnsproject@bitbucket.org/johnsproject/proj.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I have had a look at a few SO questions where they suggest the use of a force flag `-f` - but I am unsure if I should be doing this.

p.s: I am on the master branch - which is the `only` branch on my repo.

Would really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction here.

Thanks.

Comment: `Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.` Did you tried to pull?

Comment: I tried this, but I get ` * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 74f5f2e..06e5112
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.`

Comment: ok) then commit you changes and run `git pull` again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, there might be chances in your branch also, let say you are working on some other branch named "X" in this branch 2 or more people or working. And if you taken the pull from master and then pushing to this "x" branch, will through this error. you need to pull again from "X" branch and push to "X" branch.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 24):

There are changes in the central repository that you must pull before you can push.
Do

```
git add -A
git commit -m "my local changes" 
git pull
```

Resolve any conflicts. *Then* do

```
git push
```

Alternatively, if you have no valuable modifications locally, you can create a new clone of your repo, and start working from there:

```
git clone https://johnsproject@bitbucket.org/johnsproject/proj.git new_repo_dir
```

Comment: When I do git pull, I seem to get ` * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 74f5f2e..06e5112
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.`

Comment: @JohnJ Ok, follow the advice. Commit your local modifications first. Then `git pull` and resolve any conflicts.

Answer (score 11):

Try doing

```
git pull origin master
git add -A
git commit -m "modified code"
git push origin master
```

Your local repository is likely out of sync with the remote repository.

Comment: trying this with egit - bit of  a nightmare but essentially Eclipse's git synchronisation screen kept displaying old out-of-date merge conflicts. I had to stop and restart and suddenly my problems were solved. FWIW.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. I fixed by using the `git push -f` command which forces the update.

Comment: Regarding this solution, in case you have any new files that you did't pull locally, this process will delete them.

Comment: Not a good solution if you are not sure what you are pushing.

Answer (score 4):

works for me `git push --set-upstream origin master -f`

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. Nothing helped untill I tried this:

git pull --rebase origin master

After that, run push command i.e.

git push -u origin master

SOLVED FOR ME!!

Comment: While this works, it might be useful for users new to git to understand what is happening when executing these commands. You can improve your answer by explaining what the problem is (see [the answer by Klas Mellbourn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16899319/3127242)), how `git pull` solves it (see [git pull docs](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)) and why you chose to add the additional `--rebase` flag.

Answer (score 0):

in my case was new file from git repository not added, and this was the solution
1. git status (just to check)
2. git add .
3. git push -u master origin

Answer (score 0):

You can try git pull, after that git commit in studio, and after that git push origin branch name.